# NSArray in if statement strange behaviour

Tags: objective-c

i have the following two pieces of code which i think should be identical

```
int temp = [[[myArray objectAtIndex:iIndex] objectAtIndex:jIndex] state];
if (temp > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"TEST: %d",temp);
}

if ([[[myArray objectAtIndex:iIndex] objectAtIndex:jIndex] state] > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"TEST: %d",temp);
}
```

state is just an int in the objects in the array with accessor like:

```
@property (assign)int state;
```

but when state is negative, the first version works (no output), but the second version outputs (for example) "TEST: -4" (?!)

is there any obvious reason why they might be different?

Comment: if the header file with the state is not imported, then objc assumes that it returns id. Have you check you include the right headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `-objectAtIndex:` returns an `id`, the compiler will not be able to know what `-state` should return. If you did not import the header that declares `state` first, or if the property `state` has ambiguous declaration (e.g. another class has declared `@property(retain) id state` *before* your class is imported), then the compiler may infer a wrong type for `-state`.

If it infers `id`, for instance, as all pointers are nonnegative, `-4` will be implicitly viewed as `0xFFFFFFFC`, thus the > 0 condition passes.

But for code 1, you have specified that `temp` is an `int`, so even if the return value of the call is `0xFFFFFFFC`, it will be cast back to a signed value (`-4`), hence the condition fails.

The safest approach is to specify the type of `-objectAtIndex:`, i.e.

```
Foo* obj = [[myArray objectAtIndex:iIndex] objectAtIndex:jIndex];
if (obj.state > 0) {
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I I understand it right, and the two if's are *NOT* in the same method, then the second one prints an unassigned variable. the fix should go like this:

```
if ((temp = [[[myArray objectAtIndex:iIndex] objectAtIndex:jIndex] state]) > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"TEST: %d",temp);
}
```